# Parsing two messy numbers with .NET regex

Tags: .net, regex, string, split, regex-lookarounds

I have an interesting dataset of numbers that I need to replace. How can I use .NET flavored regex (probably with a lookaround) to parse the first and second number from each row using **the following algorithm**:

Strings larger than 15 symbols that contain two numbers separated by the first occurrence of `[\s\p{P}]` after 7th symbol should be split in two. One regex should extract the first substring (containing numbers, spaces, punctuations). The second regex extracts the second half.

There is not much I can do about numbers that do not have a reasonably well defined separator. In example below the first 10 rows are subjects to be split. Strings that can't be split should be picked up by either of the two regex statements. No worries about `\n`; these strings are processed individually.

```
42977424427-77927299
62 92764949 44922672
96649274796/46262299
62-96247469,74292792
69227679/69267664
47694274/42929726
42977424427/77927299
97247-2666/7224-4767
89 3644-883436749503
78-99733017785-01627
967224267
6672-2222
97694629646797496
962 44776699
942 76699466
24796427466476967
99 98448999068440722
```

So, the first regex would return:

```
42977424427
62 92764949
96649274796
62-96247469
69227679
47694274
42977424427
97247-2666
89 3644
78-99733017785
967224267
6672-2222
97694629646797496
962 44776699
942 76699466
24796427466476967
99 98448999068440722
```

and the second regex statement would return

```
77927299
44922672
46262299
74292792
69267664
42929726
77927299
7224-4767
883436749503
01627
```

[Here is](https://regex101.com/r/u6X8BQ/5) my (failing) attempt to extract the second group of numbers:

```
(?=[\d \p{P}]{15,})[\s\p{P}][\d\p{P}]{,8}
```

Comment: If you decide to down-rate the question, please kindly explain how the question can be improved. The silent downgrading is counterproductive. I still have a problem and still need the community's help.

Comment: I don't know, maybe some people feel that you try to take advantage of them, or second find your attempt is very louse and do not count it as a real attempt. Or third, some may find your problem statement unclear, not well thought through, and your example inconclusive. However, don't mind and I did not downvote.

Comment: @wp78de: thanks. I figured the same and, hence, only posted my best attempt after a few hours of trying. I find the problem well formed, but suggestions are welcome. There is a clear explanation, with a clear answer that I expect. Mind that this is a problem from a real (messy) world; and I spent the time to make a "public" sample set.

Comment: @OlegMelnikov You are saying that you need to have more then 15 symbols. But still, you want to match strings like `967224267`, `6672-2222`, `962 44776699`, `942 76699466` which have less than 15 symbols. Please clarify

Comment: @Gurman: I want to parse the string into two only if it's long enough (roughly 15 symbols) and has a separator after 7th symbol. Otherwise, leave it as is. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try this regex:

```
^(.{7}\d*)(?:[^\d\n](.*))?$
```

[Click fo Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6X8BQ/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(.{7}\d*)` - matches 7 occurrences of any character but a newline character. This is followed by 0+ occurrences of a digit. This whole value is captured in Group 1
- `(?:[^\d\n](.*))?` - matches a character that is niether a digit nor a newline. This is then followed by 0+ occurrences of any character but a newline character which is captured in Group2. `?` at the end is to make this match optional
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Another regex:

[`^([\d .,?!'":;_-]{7}\d*)(?:[^\d\n]([\d .,?!'":;_-]*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/u6X8BQ/6)

Comment: Great! I think this might work. Trying it out on the full set.

Comment: this might work, but it captures the whole string with .NET flavored regex. Works in PHP flavor, though. Is there a way to tune it for .NET?
I suppose .NET is similar to javascript
https://regex101.com/r/u6X8BQ/4

Comment: In php also it matches the complete string. You just need to fetch your results from Group1 and Group2. See the values of group1 and group2 in the right hand side in the demo link I have provided.

Comment: when I try it, .NET's `RegexReplace()` still captures the whole string, instead of just the first group or the second group. Any suggestions?

Comment: Great! Thanks. I figured out the rest. It's just what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a quiet similar [pattern](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5B%5Cd%5Cs%5Cp%7BP%7D%5D%7B7%7D%5Cd*%29%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%5Cd%5Cn%5D%28%5B%5Cd%5Cp%7BP%7D%5D%2B%29%29%3F&i=42977424427%0D%0A62%2092764949%0D%0A96649274796%0D%0A62-96247469%0D%0A69227679%0D%0A47694274%0D%0A42977424427%0D%0A97247-2666%0D%0A89%203644%0D%0A78-99733017785%0D%0A967224267%0D%0A6672-2222%0D%0A97694629646797496%0D%0A962%2044776699%0D%0A942%2076699466%0D%0A24796427466476967%0D%0A99%2098448999068440722&o=cm)

```
^([\d\s\p{P}]{7}\d*)(?:[^\d\n]([\d\p{P}]+))?$
```

that allows you to get the values from the capture groups as needed:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^([\d\s\p{P}]{7}\d*)(?:[^\d\n]([\d\p{P}]+))?$";
        string input = @"42977424427-77927299
62 92764949 44922672
96649274796/46262299
62-96247469,74292792
69227679/69267664
47694274/42929726
42977424427/77927299
97247-2666/7224-4767
89 3644-883436749503
78-99733017785-01627
967224267
6672-2222
97694629646797496
962 44776699
942 76699466
24796427466476967
99 98448999068440722";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}.....{1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Just use the groups or glue the final string together as needed.

And here is a pattern that enables your original idea of splitting:

[`(?=(?:(?:[\d\s\p{P}]{15,}).))(?<=.{7})[\s\p{P}]`](https://regex101.com/r/orRZN1/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I think I can use `RegexExtract()` for the groups, explained in https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1260635-391-1.aspx

Comment: thanks for the clarification and example! It worked great!